# Removing empty elements

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have data from people being asked for a result of the swab test - (1=pos, 2=neg, 3=not received, 4= inconclusive,9=ignored, empty cell= not applicable). I'm looking for a way to get rid of the not applicable cells. It does not say N/A or anything - they are just empty. So it looks something like this:

{,,,,,,,,,2,,,,,,1,,,,,2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,9,,,,,,1} How would I get rid of all empty ones and only keep the numbers?

Comment: Could replace `Null` with `Nothing`, among other possibilities.

Comment: To add a minor variation to Domen's repertoire of answers: `Cases[list, Except[Null]]`

Answer (score 5):

The solution depends on how the empty value are represented. Furthermore, you can use any of the many Mathematica functions, such as `DeleteCases`, `Select`, `Cases`, `Replace` ...

```
(* Empty values represented with Null *)
arr = {, , , , , , , , , 2, , , , , , 1, , , , , 2, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 9, , , , , , 1};
DeleteCases[arr, Null]
Select[arr, Not[# === Null] &]
Cases[arr, _?NumericQ]
arr /. Null -> Nothing

(* {2, 1, 2, 9, 1} *)


(* Empty values represented with "" *)
arr = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 2, "", "", "", "", "", 1, "", "", "", "", 2, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 9, "", "", "", "", "", 1};

DeleteCases[arr, ""]
Select[arr, # != "" &]
Cases[arr, _?NumericQ]
arr /. "" -> Nothing

(* {2, 1, 2, 9, 1} *)
```

Comment: Depending on where the data is coming from and how it is displayed, it might also be filled with `""` (i.e. empty strings). But only OP knows which one is true of course

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, not sure why that did not delete the empty ones. I instead of getting rid of empty ones I chose to go with Select[swabTest,NumberQ].. This then gave me only the ones with results in it.

Comment: @Pedro, I have expanded my answer with different possible ways of getting what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {, , , , , , , 2, , , , , , 1, , , , , 2, , , 9 , 1};
```

A few more possibilities:

**1.**

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Flatten @ SequenceSplit[list, {Null}]
```

{2, 1, 2, 9, 1}

Or, more generally

```
Flatten @ SequenceSplit[list, {Except[_?NumericQ]}]
```

{2, 1, 2, 9, 1}

Performance disclaimer: `SequenceSplit` gets slow with long lists.

**2.**

Using `DeleteCases`

```
DeleteCases[Except[_?NumericQ]] @ list
```

{2, 1, 2, 9, 1}

**3.**

Using `Extract`

```
Extract[Position[list, _?NumericQ]] @ list
```

{2, 1, 2, 9, 1}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {, , , , , , , 2, , , , , , 1, , , , , 2, , , 9, 1};
```

---

Using `Delete`:

```
Delete[#, Position[#, Null]] &@list

(*{2, 1, 2, 9, 1}*)
```

Or using `GroupBy`:

```
GroupBy[list, NumericQ][True]

(*{2, 1, 2, 9, 1}*)
```